# How do I include a directory (not its contents) in proguard?

Tags: proguard

I have a directory called `pngs` (containing images) that I want included in the generated jar:

```
-injars /whatever/pngs
```

However, this "flattens" the directory contents into the jar directly, without the `pngs` directory itself.

How do I include the directory `pngs` itself, not just its contents?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, filters seem to do the trick:

```
-injars /whatever(pngs/*)
```

If there is a better/more idiomatic version, let me know.